# How to properly use Bolts Framework code along with Parse and Facebook?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, bolts-framework, facebook

So,

I am building this iOS 8 app where I am using both Facebook and Parse Frameworks simultaneously. I am aware that Bolts framework is included in the latest Facebook SDK. I am attempting to use BFTasks with Parse code to make it easier to handle async taks, such as the following:

```
PFQuery *userQuery = [PFUser query];

[[userQuery findObjectsInBackground] continueWithSuccessBlock:^id(BFTask *task){

}];
```

However, including the Facebook and Parse SDKs alone won't let me access the code above via Xcode auto completion. It will even crash if I attempt to run something like the above.

On the other hand, if I try to include the Bolts Framework into the project and import the headers `#import <Bolts/Bolts.h>`, it will let me access the methods via auto-completion, but Xcode will complain saying that the there are duplicate binaries of the Bolts Framework.

Can anyone explain how to go about this or send me a link on a tutorial or something? I might be overlooking something simple.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Are you using CocoaPods by chance?

Comment: I'm having the same issue and I'm not using CocoaPods nor the Facebook framework... only parse and bolts frameworks.

Comment: Did anyone find an answer to this question? I am facing the same problem in implementation of App Links

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it going using cocoapods. So I installed bolts using cocoapods and then manually added the Parse and Facebook SDK.

I couldn't figure out how to do it otherwise

Answer (score 0):

I was having a problem with linker errors after upgrading to Parse SDK 1.9 -- references included BFTask and multiple references. Also using FB SDK 3.24 and one version using 4.7.  Same problem.  No cocoapods.  I finally resolved it by importing both FB SDK and Bolts from the FB default location -- with no copy files provision AND importing JUST Parse and ParseFacebookUtils frameworks (not their Bolts framework) with the copy files to destination = YES. So - it appears - XCode should access Bolts from the FB SDK location when needed, but NOT see the Parse Bolts framework because Parse has been copied to the app's folder, but the Parse Bolts was not.  So no double reference to Bolts. See if this helps.